# Ansible run task once per database-name

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible to deploy several sites to the same server. Each site is a separate 'host' in the ansible `hosts` inventory, which works really well.

However, there are only two databases: production and testing.
How can I make sure my database-migration task only runs once per database?

I've read into the `group_by`, `run_once` and `delegate_to` features, but I'm not sure how to combine those.

The hosts look something like:

```
[production]
site1.example.com       ansible_ssh_host=webserver.example.com
site2.example.com       ansible_ssh_host=webserver.example.com

[beta]
beta-site1.example.com  ansible_ssh_host=webserver.example.com
beta-site2.example.com  ansible_ssh_host=webserver.example.com

[all:children]
production
beta
```

The current playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
- tasks:

  # ...

  - name: "postgres:  Create PostgreSQL database"
    sudo: yes
    sudo_user: postgres
    postgresql_db: db="{{ DATABASES.default.NAME }}" state=present template=template0 encoding='UTF-8' lc_collate='en_US.UTF-8' lc_ctype='en_US.UTF-8'
    tags: postgres
    register: createdb
    delegate_to: "{{ DATABASES.default.HOST|default(inventory_hostname) }}"

  # ...

  - name: "django-post:  Create Django database tables (migrate)"
    django_manage: command=migrate app_path={{ src_dir }} settings={{ item.settings }} virtualenv={{ venv_dir }}
    with_items: django_projects
    #run_once: true
    tags:
    - django-post
    - django-db
    - migrate
```

Comment: Generally, "once per group" is not a supported semantic, and trying to get everything into a single play could be more trouble than it's worth. Just want to clarify, you want the first task to run once per host and the second exactly twice, once in each group?

Answer (score 3):

The best way I found was to restrict the execution of a task to the first host of a group. Therefore you need to add the groupname and the databases to a group_vars file like:

***group_vars/production***

```
---
dbtype=production
django_projects:
    - name: project_1
      settings: ...
    - name: project_n
      settings: ...
```

***group_vars/beta***

```
---
dbtype=beta
django_projects:
    - name: project_1
      settings: ...
    - name: project_n
      settings: ...
```

***hosts***

```
[production]
site1.example.com       ansible_ssh_host=localhost ansible_connection=local
site2.example.com       ansible_ssh_host=localhost ansible_connection=local

[beta]
beta-site1.example.com  ansible_ssh_host=localhost ansible_connection=local
beta-site2.example.com  ansible_ssh_host=localhost ansible_connection=local


[all:children]
production
beta
```

and limit the task execution to the first host that matches that group:

```
- name: "django-post:  Create Django database tables (migrate)"
  django_manage: command=migrate app_path={{ src_dir }} settings={{ item.settings }} virtualenv={{ venv_dir }}
  with_items: django_projects
  when: groups[dbtype][0] == inventory_hostname 
  tags:
    - django-post
    - django-db
    - migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

So, the below will illustrate why I say "once per group" is generally not supported. Naturally, I would love to see a cleaner out-of-the-box way, and do let me know if "once per group" isn't what you're after.

Hosts:

```
[production]
site1.example.com       ansible_ssh_host=localhost ansible_connection=local
site2.example.com       ansible_ssh_host=localhost ansible_connection=local

[beta]
beta-site1.example.com  ansible_ssh_host=localhost ansible_connection=local
beta-site2.example.com  ansible_ssh_host=localhost ansible_connection=local

[beta:vars]
dbhost=beta-site1.example.com

[production:vars]
dbhost=site1.example.com

[all:children]
production
beta
```

Example playbook which will do something on the *dbhost* once per group (the two real groups):

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: "do this once per group"
    sudo: yes
    delegate_to: localhost
    debug:
      msg: "do something on {{hostvars[groups[item.key].0]['dbhost']}} for {{item}}"
    register: create_db
    run_once: yes
    with_dict: groups
    when: item.key not in ['all', 'ungrouped']
```